# File and Printer Sharing / Samba / 139 being blocked but where

Tags: windows-7, samba, file-sharing, router

I just set up my new remote office network  the problem is i cannot access shared folders to the home office (without turning on the vpn)

I control the servers remotely but would really like to access ports 139 and 445.

The problem is that they are open on the server side but it appears as though the packets are being dropped before they get get to the server... any way i can tell where the packet is being dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking your server ports with http://www.canyouseeme.org/, this website will try to 'see' your port from the outside and check if it's accessible or not.

Comment: Open on the server

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding correctly that you're trying to access these ports across the internet, without a VPN? If so, it's an exercise in futility. Nearly all ISPs block those ports at various places within their network. You'll need to use a VPN of some sort.

Comment: my last two home offices  it worked without a hitch...   so its not some sort of far fetched idea

Comment: Well then it sounds like you got lucky. Like I said, get some sort of VPN set up. OpenVPN is very easy to configure, and you'll get the benefit of encrypted traffic along with not having to worry about those ports being blocked in transit.

Comment: I do run VPN's both microsoft native and openvpn but those route all traffic through which slows down communication to internet locations.

Comment: I don't know about Microsoft's VPN, but with OpenVPN, it's certainly possible to do "split tunneling" where only the remote subnet gets routed through the tunnel. Do you have the `redirect-gateway` option enabled on either the server or the client configs?